# Humor in Writing

Tags: creative-writing, technique, humor

I'll be honest here and say that I'm a pretty funny guy. I tend to make my friends and family laugh from time to time but I've got a problem on my hands: I have no humor in my writing.

I'm writing a Young Adult fiction and after reading books and watching movies such as Harry Potter and Lord of the Rings I've reached a conclusion I need to humor to my writing or the book will just sink. I mean who hasn't laughed at Fred and George's antics and jokes and Merry and Pippin's craziness.

How do I add humor and how can I make it work?

Thank you in advance.

Comment: Hi, and welcome to Writers. Did you browse other questions in the `humor` tag?

Comment: As written, this is an extremely broad question. You might consider looking at our site [tour] if you need clarification on this. I'm placing this question on hold for now, but if you have specific questions about humor that aren't covered elsewhere on the site, feel free to edit this question or open another one.